# Passing a slice to recursive function in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, slice, tail-recursion

I think I understand the basic principles of recursive functions and slicing (individually), but I am having trouble putting them together. I don't understand what happens when you pass a slice or a list to the following function.

```
def listSum(ls):
    # Base condition
    if not ls:
        return 0

    # First element + result of calling `listsum` with rest of the elements
    return ls[0] + listSum(ls[1:])

listSum([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
19
```

This is the thread that contains this code:
[Understanding recursion in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693819/understanding-recursion-in-python)

I think I would really benefit from a walk-through of what happens when the function is called.

The thread has a lot of examples of different recursive functions, with the expected output. I understand the subsequent examples even less than the one I copied above.

Comment: A slice simply creates a new list. You don't really pass a *slice*, you take a slice of a list to create a new list, then pass that

Comment: If you need a walk through try running your code through http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and clicking 'Visual Execution'

Comment: it adds 1 plus the rest of the list without 1, so `1 + (2 +( 3+ (4+ (5+ (6 + 0)))))`

Comment: The sum of a list is the first thing in the list (`ls[0]`) plus the sum of the rest (`listSum(ls[1:]`).

Comment: splice returns a new list. The function listSum takes a list. It's a match! The recursion is simple "sum = first + sum(rest)".

Comment: Turns out I didn't actually understand slicing. Thank you all for the replies!

Comment: Note that creating a new list for each recursive call is *very* inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept of recursion is that each call *consumes* part of the input, reducing it until it matches the *base case*.

Here, the base case is is `if not ls`, which will be true when `ls` is an empty list.

The consumption is done via slicing: each call passes a list that is one element shorter than the last one. This is accomplished with `listSum(ls1:])`, which calls `listSum` on a list composed of all elements of ls *except the first*.

That first element is then added to the result of the recursive call and returned. Since there will be one recursive call for element of `ls`, each number in `ls` gets at turn to be the one popped off and summed, that is, *consumed*.

Going through it step by step, we're going to add

> 1 + listSum( [3, 4, 5, 6] )

which is

> 1 + 3 + listSum( [4, 5, 6])

which is

> 1 + 3 + 4 + listSum( [5, 6] )

which is

> 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 + listSum( [6] )

which is

> 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + listSum([])

which, because of the base case, is

> 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 0

which is 19.

Answer (score 1):

**List traversal baby steps**

For traversing lists using recursion, there's only 3 things that matter

- the empty list - always check if your list is empty before anything!
- the head of the list – the first item
- the tail of the list – the entire list *except* the first item

Ok, and here's the functions we'll use to write our programs

```
def is_empty (ls):
  return ls == []

def head (ls):
  return ls[0]

def tail (ls):
  return ls[1:]
```

Usage of the functions is straightforward

```
is_empty ([])           # => True
is_empty ([ 1, 2, 3 ])  # => False

head ([ 1, 2, 3 ])      # => 1

tail ([ 1, 2, 3 ])      # => [2,3]
```

Ok, so let's write our `list_sum` function – I think you'll agree that we ended up with a very readable program thanks to the list helpers we defined

```
def list_sum (ls):
  if is_empty (ls):
    return 0
  else:
    return head (ls) + list_sum (tail (ls))

print (list_sum ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]))
# => 28
```

But you tagged this with tail recursion, so with the help of an optional parameter and a default value, we can move the recursive call into tail position. Changes in **bold**

```
def list_sum (ls, acc = 0):
  if is_empty (ls):
    return acc
  else:
    return list_sum (tail (ls), head (ls) + acc)

print (list_sum ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]))
# => 28
```

But Python doesn't really have tail-call elimination, so you'd still have to do [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268042/633183) to ensure stack-safety.

---

**Smoke higher-order functions every day**

Using `head` and `tail` relieved us from the tedium (and ugliness) of `[0]` and `[1:]`, but this pattern of list traversal is so common that we can relieve ourselves from even thinking at this level altogether!

Let's look back at our function, `list_sum`. This function traverses a list and performs addition using the built-in `+` function. What if instead of `+` we wanted to multiply all the elements using `*`?

```
def list_sum (ls):
  if is_empty (ls):
    return 0
  else:
    return head (ls) + list_sum (tail (ls))

def list_product (ls):
  if is_empty (ls):
    return 1
  else:              
    return head (ls) * list_product (tail (ls))

print (list_product ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]))
# => 5040
```

The only thing that's different is `0` changed to `1` and `+` changed to `*`. We don't want to rewrite all of that each time we want to do something with a list. If we abstract those values using function parameters, we can capture the very essence of list traversal in this nice little program

```
from operator import add, mul

def list_reduce (f, acc, ls):
  if is_empty (ls):
    return acc
  else:
    return list_reduce (f, f (acc, head (ls)), tail (ls))

def list_sum (ls):
  return list_reduce (add, 0, ls)

def list_product (ls):
  return list_reduce (mul, 1, ls)

print (list_sum ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]))
# => 28

print (list_product ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]))
# => 5040
```

And higher-order functions can be built using other higher-order functions. Then before you know it, you're doing all sorts of high-level transformations and traversals!

Notice how we're not thinking about `head` or `tail` at this point. Hard-on-brain things like `not []`, `ls[0]` and `ls[1:]` are out-of-sight and consequently out-of-mind.

```
def map (f, ls):
  return list_reduce (lambda acc, x: acc + [ f (x) ], [], ls)

def square (x):
  return x * x

print (map (square, [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]))
# => [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```