# Iterating through a list using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to use recursion to compare values of elements between two lists. For an index `i`, `if list1[i] = A and list2[i] = T` and vice versa, the values are valid. Also, for an index i, `if list1[i] = G and list2[i] = C` and vice versa, the values are valid. However, if these two conditions are not met (`list1[i] = A and list2[i] = G`), then the values are not valid. I created two new lists where valid values are stores and invalid values are replaced with blanks ' '.

This code works fine with a for loop (`for i in range (0, len(list1)):`) but how would one use recursion?

```
def check_valid(sequence1, sequence2):

 sequence1 = list(sequence1)

 sequence2 = list(sequence2)

 valid_units1 = []

 valid_units2 = []

    if (sequence1[i] == 'A' and sequence2[i] == 'T') or (sequence1[i] == 'T' and sequence2[i] == 'A'):
        valid_units1.append(sequence1[i])
        valid_units2.append(sequence2[i])
    elif (sequence1[i] == 'G' and sequence2[i] == 'C') or (sequence1[i] == 'C' and sequence2[i] == 'G'):
        valid_units1.append(sequence1[i])
        valid_units2.append(sequence2[i])
    else:
        valid_units1.append(' ')
        valid_units2.append(' ')

    print(valid_units1)
    print(valid_units2)

    valid_units = [valid_units1, valid_units2]
    return valid_units
```

Comment: I think you should ask *if* one should use recursions. It doesn't seem to have any benefit here. And this can be done with `zip()` and a simple list comprehension.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Python, not sure what a zip() or a list comprehension are. Would you mind explaining what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting with two lists and want to compare them element-wise you can use `zip()` to simplify your life. It will give you back the elements paired off. So if you are starting with two lists, you can `zip` them:

```
list1 = ['A', 'T']
list2 = ['C', 'G']

zipped = list(zip(list1, list2))
# zipped is [('A', 'C'), ('T', 'G')]

#or use a list comprehension:
zipped = [pair for pair in  zip(list1, list2)]
```

`zip()` returns an iterator which is why it's wrapped in `list()` above. If you use it in a loop or other situation calling for a interator, you don't need to do that.

If you want to compare these you can use a dictionary that defines which letter maps to the other, this will allow you write a much simpler test function:

```
# Define a mapping that describes which elements belong togethre
pairs = {
    'G':'T',
    'T':'G',
    'C':'A',
    'A':'C'
}

list1 = ['A', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A']
list2 = ['C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'T']

# make a new list if the pairs line up with the mapping:
legal = [(a, b) for a, b in  zip(list1, list2) if pairs[a] == b ]

# legal pairs: [('A', 'C'), ('T', 'G'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'A')]
```

There's not much reason to do this recursively, but you of course can. Since `zip()` returns an iterator (`pairs` below) you can call `next()` on it to get there next value and then pass the iterator back. It will throw a `StopIteration` error when it's out of items, so that can be the edge condition of the recursion:

```
def buildList(pairs, mapping):
    ''' Takes an iterator and mapping, returns a list of legal items defined by mapping '''
    try:
        a_pair = next(pairs)  # get first item from zipped list
    except StopIteration:   # no more items, just return an empty list
        return []

    a, b = a_pair            
    if mapping[a] == b:    
        return [(a, b)] + buildList(pairs, mapping)
    else: 
        return buildList(pairs, mapping)


list1 = ['A', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A']
list2 = ['C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'T']
pairs = {'G':'T','T':'G','C':'A','A':'C'}

buildList(zip(list1, list2), pairs) # use zip to make the zipped iterator
```

Comment: Thank you for all the effort you put into explaining this!

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged with *recursion* and here's my take on it -

```
def head(xs = []):
  return xs[0]

def tail(xs = []):
  return xs[1:]

def check_pair(x = "", y = "", swap = True):
  if x == "A" and y == "C":
    return True
  elif x == "G" and y == "T":
    return True
  else:
    return swap and check_pair(y, x, False)

def check_valid(a = [], b = []):
  if (not a) or (not b):
    return
  elif check_pair(head(a), head(b)):
    yield (head(a), head(b))
    yield from check_valid(tail(a), tail(b))
  else:
    yield from check_valid(tail(a), tail(b))


a = ['A', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A']
b = ['C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'T']

print(list(check_valid(a,b)))
# [('A', 'C'), ('T', 'G'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'A')]
```

This is intuitive, but like `zip`, the `tail` function creates intermediate values. We can reduce memory requirement by using a simple index, `i` -

```
def check_pair(x = "", y = "", swap = True):
  if x == "A" and y == "C":
    return True
  elif x == "G" and y == "T":
    return True
  else:
    return swap and check_pair(y, x, False)

def check_valid(a = [], b = [], i = 0):
  if i >= min(len(a), len(b)):
    return
  elif check_pair(a[i], b[i]):
    yield (a[i], b[i])
    yield from check_valid(a, b, i + 1)
  else:
    yield from check_valid(a, b, i + 1)

a = ['A', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A']
b = ['C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'T']

print(list(check_valid(a,b)))
# [('A', 'C'), ('T', 'G'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'A')]
```

You may be interested in this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268042/633183)